# Possible circular import issue in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying a simple rest api in flask and basic stuff works. When I try to introduce DB, it's failing on imports for model

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_migrate import Migrate

import redis from rq import Queue

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from models import OcrText
```

**models.py**

```
from app import db

class OcrText(db.Model):
    # schema
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "app.py", line 21, in <module> from models import OcrText
File "/Users/anibara/Learn/Flask/ml_ocr/models.py", line 1, in <module> from app import db
File "/Users/anibara/Learn/Flask/ml_ocr/app.py", line 21, in <module> from models import OcrText
ImportError: cannot import name 'OcrText'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, it is a circular import issue. Just move the DB initialization to a new file like `db.py` and import this file from `app.py` and `models.py`. This way it will work fine.

Example `db.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = None


def init_db(app):
    global db

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

    return db
```

Example `app.py`

```
from db import init_db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
init_db(app)

from models import OcrText
```

Example `models.py`

```
from db import db

class OcrText(db.Model):
    # schema
```